# How can I loop over zsh array and use index and value in other commands?

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0)
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.2a
```

I am automating a remote server monitoring dashboard in tmux via zsh script.

1. Store the multiline output of a command as an array in zsh:   (WORKS)

```
$ server_name_array=( $( aws ec2 describe-instances... ) )
$ declare -p server_name_array
typeset -a server_name_array=( name1 name2 name3 )
```

2. Then want to use both the index and value of each array item in my tmux command:    (DOES NOT WORK)

```
$ for i in "${!server_name_array[@]}"; \
do \
  tmux send-keys -t '=server:=servers.<server_name_index>' 'ssh <server_name_value> -t "<my-remote-command>"'; \
done;
```

But I get the following error:

`zsh: event not found: server_name_array[@]`

I have [read](https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found) this is due to the special `!` operator in bash and have tried escaping / unsetting it as suggested to no avail:

```
$ set +H
$ for index in "${"'!'"server_name_array[@]}"; do echo $index; done;
zsh: bad substitution
$ for index in "${"\!"server_name_array[@]}"; do echo $index; done;
zsh: bad substitution
$ for index in "${"'!'"server_name_array[@]}"; do echo $index; done;
zsh: bad substitution
$ for index in "${"\!"server_name_array[@]}"; do echo $index; done;
zsh: bad substitution
$ for index in "${!server_name_array[@]}"; do echo $index; done;
zsh: event not found: server_name_array[@]
$ for index in "${\!server_name_array[@]}"; do echo $index; done;
zsh: bad substitution
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

Here is my script invoked via .sh file:

```
$ ls -ahl /usr/local/bin/server_mon
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  admin    48B <date> /usr/local/bin/server_mon -> ~/scripts/server_mon.sh
```

```
#!/bin/sh

set -euC

cd <project-directory>

# our main function
attach() {
    [ -n "${TMUX:-}" ] &&
        tmux switch-client -t '=server' ||
        tmux attach-session -t '=server'
}

# attach to server if it already exists
if tmux has-session -t '=server' 2> /dev/null; then
    attach
    exit 0
fi

# start a named session called server
tmux new-session -d -s 'server' -n 'local'; \

# new tmux servers window
tmux new-window -d -t '=server' -n 'servers'; \

# store the names of our server instances in an array
server_name_array=( $( aws ec2 describe-instances ... ) )
declare -p server_name_array
# typeset -a server_name_array=( name1 name2 name3 )
server_name_array_length=${#server_name_array[@]:1}

# create split panes for number of servers (n-1)
for i in "${server_name_array[@]:1}"; do tmux split-window -t '=server:=servers' -d; done;
# select an even vertical layout
tmux select-layout -t '=server:=servers' even-vertical;

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# HERE IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

# Loop over ZSH array of server names, and send ssh commands containing server names to panes via the array index
for i in "${!server_name_array[@]}"; 
do
    # tmux send-keys -t '=server:=servers.<server_name_index>' 'ssh <server_name_value> -t "<my-remote-command>"';
    tmux send-keys -t '=server:=servers.${$i}' 'ssh ${server_name_array[$i] -t "sudo su;"' Enter; 
done;
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" -- in my opinion, trying to write a program that both bash and zsh can run. Pick one or the other.

Comment: @glennjackman My script has `#!/bin/sh` at the top.  I'm using zshell in terminal.  Testing these command I am using the terminal.  When I run the script aliased to <script.sh>, is ZSH running it or BASH?

Comment: clearly zsh is, as you get the zsh error. Show the content of the script and especially show exactly how you invoke it.

Comment: @eschie If you're using a generic `#!/bin/sh` shebang, you shouldn't use any non-POSIX features (like arrays) at all, because you aren't in control of which shell the scripts runs under. Do not worry about figuring out what /bin/sh is on your system, because that's [subject to change](https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/). If you want to use non-POSIX features, you should pick a specific shell, use a shebang that specifies that shell, and then use that shell's syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following script produces same result in bash and zsh :

```
declare -a server_name_array=(a b c)

test "$ZSH_VERSION" && c=1 || c=0

for ((i=0; i<${#server_name_array[@]}; i++)); do
    echo $i "${server_name_array[i+c]}"
done
```

output :

```
$ bash test.sh
0 a
1 b
2 c
$ zsh  test.sh
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Comment: I'm on `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)` and I don't get the same result.

Comment: @MehrshadKhansarian I get same result on `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0)`. Can you post your result ?

Comment: I am sorry, I was mistaken. I hadn't noticed the `i+c` index, which practically starts indexing at 1 on zsh and 0 on bash.